# Cannot get my divs to line up side-by-side and fill the page's height

Tags: html, css

I have the following ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaJ3r/)):

```
<div class="content_wrap">
    <div class="left_container">
    </div>

    <div class="right_container">
        <div style="background-color: blue; margin:20px; height: 1500px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

div.content_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.left_container {
    float:left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

div.right_container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
}

.clear { clear: both; }
```

​What I'm trying to do is line the `div`s side by side and have the left side bar (red) stretch to either the height of the page, or the height taken up by the content (which is in blue), which ever is greater (like the layout shown [here](http://demo.themezilla.com/artiste/))

My problems at the moment are:
The content of the right container (The blue box is just to illustrate content) does not align properly next to the left container
The left container doesn't adjust its height according to the content of the right container.

I've put in a clear fix, although to be quite honest, I don't completely understand how that works.

Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: class `.clear` is never used as you named it `class='clearfix'` in the html

Comment: @scooper can i give you jquery solution if you dont mind?

Comment: @HappySingh Need a css only one, thanks though!

Comment: I have created fiddle for you so i thought you might like to see atleast once http://jsfiddle.net/PaJ3r/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PaJ3r/9/
Here is updated CSS for it:

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

div.content_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

div.left_container {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

div.right_container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: 220px;
    padding-top:100px;
    width: 1000px;
}

.clear { clear: both; }
```

`position:relative` in `div.content_wrap` is needed in order to get left sidebar stretched to the height of content.
`position:absolute;` in `div.left_container` allows left container to fit height of wrapper div.
In `div.right_container` there is `margin-left: 220px;` which leave left sidebar visible

Comment: This is the only solution that addresses the height issue, thanks.

Comment: Just one more thing: if they height of the right content is less than that of the page height, I want the left container's height to fill the page. How would I go about doing that? Setting the height of `content_wrap` to `100%` doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaJ3r/2/).

So few remarks: I used `float: left;` on both `div`s and also, as bart said, you didn't use the correct name for `clearfix`.

Answer (score 1):

First you should nest your div's so that the `left` `div` can grow with the right one.

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaJ3r/3/)

For the `left` `div` not set the `height`, but the `min-heigth` to 100%. Furthermore you need to play around with margins and paddings to get the last bit ok